A guy in prison and is writing back and forth to a model
I watched it 4 years ago on normal cable tv. Motel room TV channels. I want to say it's older than that. It's about a guy who's in prison and is writing back and forth to this modeling girl but when he gets out and goes to the house the house is torn down. He told her he had this huge diamond. He hires a detective to find this girl and when he does he find that this hippy with long hair guy (I want to say it was her dad) built a tunnel because the equator is going to hit this certain spot and they're going to catch it all on record. 
In the end, the detective and some other guys are in a room and they found the diamond it's in a lizard/snake tank. The prisoner eventually comes to the house and finds the girl he was looking for. The movie was crazy.

country/language?

The Big Bang
From IMDB 

A private detective is hired to find a missing stripper. A simple job turns complicated when everyone he questions ends up dead.

From another plot summary at IMDB

The washed up boxer Anton 'The Pro' Protopov comes to his office to hire him to find his missing girlfriend and former stripper Lexie Persimmon. Cruz recalls that five years ago, the Russian mobster Skinny Faddeev gave 30 million dollars in blood diamond in advance to him to lose a fight against his nephew. However, Anton killed the nephew with a punch and when Skinny was found death, he was sentenced to life. Lexie writes two hundred and sixty letters to him and they fall in love for each other. When a criminal confesses the murder of Skinny, Anton is released but he does not find Lexie.
When Cruz is invited to have dinner with the delusional millionaire Simon Kestral (The guy with long hair), he is introduced to his wife Julie Kestral (He'll assume she's the woman he's looking for) and the geek physicist Niels Geck (In the end he'll find out that this guy was the one writting the letters) and he believes he has resolved the case. However, nothing is what seems to be and Cruz only discovers the truth when it is late.

Also the detective and the other guys were all dirty cops trying to find the diamond




Thank you so much! I have no idea how you could possibly understand what I was trying to explain but thank you so much!

u r welcome and actually it was a well detailed question. Also, don't forget to to close the question by accepting the answer
